# Need to write an AND regex in ruby

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will check if a string starts with `"V "` and then if it also has the word `'BENCH'` or `'EARCX'` in it.

My current expression was written as: `V\s|BENCH|EARCX`
however I realized that it was taking anything with `'V '` or `BENCH` or `EARCX`.  Is there an `AND` condition for regular expressions in ruby?  If so, how can I get it to check for both the `'V '` and `BENCH` or `EARCX`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For trying around you may want to use the "Ruby regular expression editor" on http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If order matters (as you say, "starts with V"), you can write simply:

```
/V.*(BENCH|EARCX)/
```

If it does not, you can wrap in another alternation:

```
/V.*(BENCH|EARCX)|(BENCH|EARCX).*V/
```

But this is getting unwieldy (especially if you have several different AND factors, so better to use lookaheads:

```
/(?=.*V)(?=.*(BENCH|EARCX))/
```

This will match `VBENCH`, `EARCXfooV`... and is the solution for a general case AND anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `and` when you write something sequentially it's automatically `and`.

try:

```
V\s(BENCH|EARCX)
```

it will accept

> V BENCH
>   V EARCX

and reject

> V abcd

Or you can make the space optional if you want

```
V(\s)?(BENCH|EARCX)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^V\s.*?\b(?:BENCH|EARCX)\b.*$
```

You will have to use anchors.`^$` will make regex do a strict matching rather than partial matching.